# How do I Query 2 Custom Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types

This is what I have, it **works** great except it only pulls from one CPT. I need it to pull from **two**.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 
     'post_type' => 'Portfolio' , 'Artwork' ) );
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;   $the_post_ids = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

If I use something like this as suggested elsewhere:

```
<?php query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => array( 'artwork', 'portfolio' ));
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; $the_post_ids = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

It doesn't work at all with parse errors that I cannot seem to fix. Unexpected ";". I am fairly new, could someone suggest something to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Firstly*, do not use `query_post()`, there almost never is reason to do so - take a look at [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/22534).

*Secondly*, read the documentation about the things you want to achieve, here [WP_Query - Type Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters).

*Thirdly*, take a close look at what you're writing/copying there might be a syntax error in it, that's what you're telling us is implying.

All that said, the following should do the trick.

**Code:**

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => array( 'artwork', 'portfolio' )
) );
```

Comment: I would have never thought to add another ")". Outside of that I am very tight with syntax and am familiar with the documentation listed (not necessarily understanding it). Thank you very much for all the suggestions.

Comment: My pleasure. One gets to see those things, practice and constant learning, that's just it. @user46040